# Dictionary Checking

Tags: c#, dictionary, contains

I have a list and I am getting each item in the list in a `foreach` loop.

```
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFile1.FileName);
                int i = 1;

                Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                foreach (var line in theFinalList)
                {
                    //compareList.Add(line.PartNumber[]);
                    if (!line.Name.Contains("FID") || !line.PartNumber.Contains("FIDUCIAL") ||
                        !line.PartNumber.Contains("EXCLUDES") || !line.PartNumber.Contains("excludes"))
                    {
                        //This doesn't work obviously.. :/
                        sw.WriteLine("( {0} 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"\" {3} 0 0 0 0 0 )",
                            i, line.PartDescription, line.PartNumber, partNumberOccurrences);
                    }

                    i++;
                }
            }
```

And I am having trouble using a dictionary to store each part of the line in a dictionary and to increment the the itemCounter whenever it is found as duplicate. I am trying to do something like this, but I cannot figure out the logic for it.

And I would like to only output the partNumber 1 time and also the amount of times it occurred as well as a corresponding value on the same line as the partNumber.

The output would look like this:

```
( 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "136380" "" 18 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 2 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "128587" "" 41 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 3 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "138409" "" 11 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 4 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "110984" "" 8 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 5 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "3216R_1.3" "114441" "" 6 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 6 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "3216C_1.3" "2006722" "" 16 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 7 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "3216C_1.3" "135732" "" 6 0 0 0 0 0 )
```

Can anyone help me with creating a dictionary to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (string word in lineList)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word)
        dictionary[word]++;
    else
        dictionary[word] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a new class for your items and store a List of these items and then use Linq to group the results - you may or may not find it more logical:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; } // I did this as string rather than int
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
```

Then, you seem to want to be grouping the items (this example uses Linq and assumes you have populated your items List):

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, MyItem>> grouped = items
    .GroupBy(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.PartNumber))
    .OrderBy(t => t.Key);

foreach(var item in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number of Occurances:" + item.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item.ElementAt(0).Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Description: " + item.ElementAt(0).Description);
    Console.WriteLine("\n --------------------------------- \n");
}
```

This example assumes that everything with the same part number will have the same name and description.

Comment: I tried inserting this into the code but it seems to have problems with the `.Orderby(t => t.Key)` part... could you help me solve this issue?

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOOrderedEnumerable<System.Linq.IGroping<string,Balancer.mainForm.MyItem>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.Igrouping<int,Balancer.mainForm.MyItem>>'. An explicit conversion  exists (are you missing a cast?)` is what is says..

Comment: Ah yes. That's because PartNumber is a string in my example. I will ammend my answer.

Comment: There is no longer an error.. but when i try to run it nothing shows up as outputted.. :/

Comment: It works fine for me in my tests. Are you sure you are calling the group function on the right thing etc and you are calling Console.WriteLine on the right thing?

Comment: I believe everything is correct.. the only thing changed was `Console` to `StreamWriter`

Comment: Great, you should be able to work out how to write to file from what I pasted. You simply need to change what's inside the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
int value;
if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(line.PartNumber, out value))
{
    value = 0;
}
dictionary[line.PartNumber] = value + 1;
```

Comment: You don't need the `if`; `TryGetValue` will put the `default(int)` (aka 0) into `value` if the key isn't found.

Comment: @Daniel: So how would I print this out to a `StreamWriter` file?

Comment: As you only save partnumber and the occurences count in the dictionary, there is no clean way to output what you want from the dictionary. A cleaner approach would be the answer by AndyC. However, I don't think that you need to create a new class, because your class in `theFinalList` already seems to be holding all the data you need.

Comment: @Daniel: Oh Okay.. I was trying something like: `sw.WriteLine(dictionary[line.PartNumber] + " " + value);` but I have a feeling that is **WAY** off.. lol

Comment: @theNoobGuy: If you just want to output the data of the dictionary after you are done creating it, you can use this: `foreach(var kvp in dictionary) sw.WriteLine(kvp.Key+" "+kvp.Value);`

Comment: @Daniel: So the above code would go inside of my foreach loop and then the foreach loop that you wrote above this comment would also go inside my foreach loop? or am i not seeing this right?

Comment: The code from my answer goes inside your `foreach (var line in theFinalList)`. The code from my comment that output the directory goes **after** that loop: `foreach (var line in theFinalList) { /* add to dictionary - see answer */ } foreach(var kvp in dictionary) sw.WriteLine(kvp.Key+" "+kvp.Value);`

Comment: @theNoobGuy: I think AndyC's answer is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could also use anonymous types along with linq to give you a neater solution. Here's an example assuming that your lines are tab separated.

```
        var lines = new[]
                        {
                            "R80\t123456\tsomething here1",
                            "R81\t123456\tsomething here1",
                            "R81\t123456\tsomething here1",
                        };

        var items = lines.Select(i => i.Split('\t')).Select(i => new {Name = i[0], PartNumber = i[1], Description = i[2]});

        var outLines =
            items.GroupBy(i => i.Name).Select(
                i =>
                string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", i.First().Name, i.First().PartNumber, i.First().Description,
                              i.Count()));

        foreach (var outLine in outLines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(outLine);
        }

        Console.Read();
```

Comment: When using this I seem to get an output that is: **System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,<>f__AnonymousType0`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]],System.String]**

Comment: that's because you are writing the collection object rather than each item in the collection. I've edited the example to make this more obvious